# owl-carousel box-shadow adds white border

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel, owl-carousel

I'm using ouwl carousel for the home page carousel.

here you have the [example](http://www.centros-sbc.com/en/home/)

The problem is the white border created on the bottom and the right parts.

I've read that applying: display:block; line-height:0;
but nothing worked

here you have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ft0pnm2j/1/) (it works fine sometimes, no border (i don't know why)) with only the carousel, for testing if you want.

Move the window size of the result for better experience with the carousel images.

I'm aplying the shadow to the div converted to carousel:

```
#carousel{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
box-sizing:border-box;
background-size: 100%;
height: auto;
display: block;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 5px;
line-height: 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
-moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
box-shadow: 4px 4px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
```

}

Comment: This was nothing to do with [tag:owl], the Web Ontology Language.  Please be sure to read the tag descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to give the **.owl-wrapper-outer** the box-shadow (only works if your images are the same size).

If your images are smaller, then give the images a box-shadow and **.owl-item** a padding, if the box-shadow is cut off.